# ¿Como realizar una auto asociación en EntityFramework Core 7? Un usuario con un listado de amigos del tipo Usuario

Tags: c#, sql-server, base-de-datos, asp.net, entity-framework

Estoy creando una API en ASP.NET Core para hacer una simulación de una red social. Estoy utilizando EF Core 7 Code First para modelar mi base de datos. Mi problema es que tengo una tabla de Usuarios, y quiero que un usuario pueda tener muchos amigos del tipo Usuario, es decir tener una lista de amigos del tipo 'User' en mi entidad 'User', como podría modelar esto?

Comment: Ya creaste una llave foránea entre las dos tablas?
eso en automático debería de darte la posibilidad de hacer la lista que quieres.

Answer (score 0):

Una relación de muchos a muchos contra la misma entidad se hace simplemente agregando una lista (`list`) a la entidad del mismo tipo.

```
public class Usuario
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    //ESTO HAY QUE AGREGAR
    public List<Usuario> Amigos { get; set; } = new List<Usuario>();
}
```

Comment: Cuando hago eso me genera solamente una FK en mi tabla Usuarios que es UserId.

Comment: @FranciscoEchenique Esto debería generarte una tabla con 3 campos `id`, `Name` y `UsuarioId` lo cual es lo correcto (a menos que yo haya entendido mal tu pregunta)